# BlockChain.info Investments? Sounds like a scam

Tags: blockchain.info, investing

Today I received a strange email, which looks like a scam to me. It claims to be sent from blockchain.info `no-reply@blockchain.info`, but being a programmer, I know that I can send email from whomever I want, so I do not trust it so much.

> Welcome to BlockChain.info Investments, a place of stable income.
>
> This email is sent to all Bitcoin members. If you are not Blockchain
>   user, you can still invest with us. All you have to do is choose
>   amount you want to invest and send it to Bitcoin address below.
>
> Minimum investment is 0.1 BTC or 50$ USD More you invest, more you
>   earn.  This is not a ponzi, we are paying our valuable members from
>   advertising money and fees.  This Investment option will be available
>   for limited time only.
>
> Example: Invest 0.1 BTC - 1 BTC - Receive 105% after 1 day. Invest 1.1
>   BTC - 2 BTC - Receive 110% after 1 day. Invest 2.1 BTC - 5 BTC -
>   Receive 115% after 1 day. Invest 5 BTC or more and receive 120% after
>   1 day.
>
> For example if you invest 1 BTC, you will receive 1.05 BTC after 24
>   hours. Invest 10 BTC and receive 12 BTC after 24 hours.
>
> Payments will be made automatically 24 hours after you send money. You
>   will receive email confirmation after you send money to our Bitcoin
>   address for investments.
>
> When you are ready to invest, choose amount and send it to this
>   address below. 1LFHVdwAV9w994sMi6o1JpJeykZhdbGfpn Every user will
>   receive custom address for deposits and withdrawals.
>
> Blockchain Team.

I formatted it a little bit, but basically this is it. Also this does not look like a ponzi scheme to me, it looks like a scam. Moreover I haven't found any information about `blockchain investments` on their site (but I admit I have not looked too much).

My question is: is this a real thing?

Comment: You're kidding, right? This is obviously a scam.

Comment: Could you please add email header information? It could show some interesting information. :) Here's how you can get header information: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en — It will show from where you received the email. It looks like l scam already, just we could get some interesting information out of headers. :D

Answer (score 12):

It seems obvious to me that this is a scam. No legitimate investment in the world can guarantee a rate of return of 20 percent per day. At that rate, with a 5 btc initial investment, you'd own all the bitcoins in existence after 81 days.  And after 15 months, you'd have [this much](http://what-if.xkcd.com/96/).

But you may want to contact blockchain.info directly; there is a contact link at the bottom of their home page. They can confirm that this is a scam, and also announce it on their blog / Twitter feed to hopefully keep anyone from falling for it.

Answer (score 9):

Obviously, he is a scammer trying hard to look similar as the Blockchain's Official Investment scheme but there isn't anything like this ever before.

Many scammers are there, one of the most luring advert is 'Earn through Bitcoin Mining from Antminer(S9)'.

In the name of Antminer(S9) many persons reaching out through various social platforms to you and giving jaw dropping ROI like 300% in 7 days but this is nothing but an assured scam.

## How do they doing it these days ?

First of all they will ask you if you have any BTC holdings.

Now they will say that they mining with any firm/locally with Antminer (S9) and they are looking more investors to connect with them.

They may send you a fake website to submit your details accordingly:

1. Name
2. Email
3. State
4. Country
5. BTC address (to receive returns)

May be some more things.

Once done these steps, now two things.

## Address of Company

Now they will send you address of company(fraud) to fund that address with btc minimum limit of 0.1btc( for example). This will be your investment.

## Blockchain Wallet

• You will be asked to create new blockchain wallet.

• Now you have to send them your details(email and password) of the Newly created Empty Blockchain wallet saying they will connecting your wallet to their Antminers and once done connecting, you can change your Blockchain password.

• After doing this you will be asked to fund that wallet according to plans they have provided you.

• You will be assured to receive funds afterwards but what will you get is a block from those guys.

## How they will sweep your Blockchain account secured with a new password  ?

• Here is the main thing most of users don't know and end up being a victim.

1. Blockchain.info provides seed words that can be used in case you lost your credentials.

   2. When you created a new wallet and send them as to connect with Antminers. They note down your wallet seeds.

      3. After you changed password and funded your wallet thinking it is secured with a new password they can access it now with those 'seed words' and your wallet funds will gone forever.